# How to use For loop with char?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, char

- By using a for loop. I want to let the user input the amount of lemonade that they want to order. Then my program will calculate the tax, subtotal, and total. After it should let them continue by either entering 'y' or 'n'.
- When I compile these codes. All I get are blanks. What is wrong with my codes?

So I made some changes. But I don't know how to have it stop the program if I enter 'n' if they ask to continue.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int NumCups;
    float SubTot, Tot = 0, Tax;
    char more;

    printf("Enter the number of cups:");
    scanf("%d", &NumCups);
    SubTot = NumCups*1.29;
    Tax = SubTot*0.0825;
    Tot = SubTot + Tax;

    printf("Subtotal:%0.2f\nTax:%0.2f\nTotal:%0.2f\n", SubTot, Tax, Tot);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Thank you.\nWould you like to order more lemonade?\n");

    for (; scanf("%c", &more);)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of cups:");
        scanf("%d", &NumCups);

        SubTot = NumCups*1.29;
        Tax = SubTot*0.0825;
        Tot += SubTot + Tax;
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Subtotal:%0.2f\nTax:%0.2f\nTotal:%0.2f\n", SubTot, Tax, Tot);
        printf("Thank you.\nWould you like to order more lemonade?\n");
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: you're expecting that some symbol should be entered first only then you will ask for number of cups

Comment: Not related to your problem, but note that you should use `int main()` instead of `void main()`. Also, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour. (This might be related to your problem.) Also, please post a compilable example, stating the expected output and actual output explicitly.

Comment: @ace I made some changes.

Comment: What's the point of `count`? I don't see it used anywhere other than being incremented (for no apparent reason?). Why not just use a while loop? I think it would be more appropriate for your program.

Comment: @digitalninja the assignment was to use a for loop.

Comment: It seems odd that they are asking for a `for` loop to be used like that... Are you sure you're interpreting the problem description correctly? Should you be asking for the amount of cups then (`for`) looping until you reach said amount or something?

Comment: @digitalninja hmmmm I am suppose to keep for looping until the user enters 'n' so they the program will stop. Also, isn't for loop exit controlled, so I would need to run the program once before looping?

Comment: try `for (; 1 == scanf(" %c", &more) && 'y' == more;)` also use do-while.

Comment: @bluepixy hmm that worked! Can you explain to me why it did?

Comment: `1 == scanf(" %c", &more)` :  There was a character input of non-blank. `&& 'y' == more` : And it was a `'y'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 for (; scanf("%c", &more)&&more=='y';)
```

This change will let you continue only when you use the y character.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    printf("Enter the number of cups:");
    scanf("%d", &NumCups);

    SubTot = NumCups*1.29;
    Tax = SubTot*0.0825;
    Tot += SubTot + Tax;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Subtotal:%0.2f\nTax:%0.2f\nTotal:%0.2f\n", SubTot, Tax, Tot);
    printf("Thank you.\nWould you like to order more lemonade?\n");
} while(1 == scanf(" %c", &more) && 'y' == more);
```